# File reading returns repeats twice

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that reads a .txt file and returns the line value of specific given line.

My problem is when I am setting variable to store first and second line of a config file it returns only the second line for both the variable.

My function:

```
char *get_config(char *fileName, int lineNumber, char *dst, int dstlen)
{

FILE *file;
file = fopen(fileName, "r");
int count = 0;

if (file != NULL)
{
    static char singleLine[150];
    while (fgets(singleLine, sizeof singleLine, file) != NULL)
    {
        if (count == lineNumber - 1)
        {
            char *line;

            if ( (line=strchr(singleLine, '\n')) != NULL)
            {
                *line = '\0';
                strncpy(dst, singleLine, dstlen);
            }
            //strcpy(dst, singleLine); // NOT SAFE!!! should use strncpy
            strncpy(dst, singleLine, dstlen);

        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    printf("Configuration file is empty.");
}

fclose(file);

}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
int main(){
    char server_url[150];
    char api_key[150];

    get_config("config.txt", 1, server_url,  sizeof server_url);
    get_config("config.txt", 2, api_key,  sizeof api_key);

    printf("%s\n", server_url);
    printf("%s\n", api_key);
}
```

config.txt file:

asdasdsad
http://172.30.20.105:8000/service/logs
6aa2afd2-ab74-43df-87ed-460441d4a5ad

Output:

```
deojeff@linux:~/DeojeffFolder/rms-datalogger$ ./read_config 
6aa2afd2-ab74-43df-87ed-460441d4a5ad
6aa2afd2-ab74-43df-87ed-460441d4a5ad
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Seems like you should increment count after you copy the line you want as well, otherwise it's the same value the next time a line is read.  You might consider breaking the loop when you've got the line you want so you don't read the whole file for line 1.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added count++ after copying the file, compile and it works. Thanks very much. :'-)

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't do what you think it does. Your comment about "not safe" is ironic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why your `get_config` function returns a pointer to `char`, however, I see two ways to solve the problem without rewriting the loop:

Adding `break;`

```
    while (fgets(singleLine, sizeof singleLine, file) != NULL)
    {
        if (count == lineNumber - 1)
        {
            char *line;

            if ( (line=strchr(singleLine, '\n')) != NULL)
            {
                *line = '\0';
                strncpy(dst, singleLine, dstlen);
            }
            //strcpy(dst, singleLine); // NOT SAFE!!! should use strncpy
            strncpy(dst, singleLine, dstlen);

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Or moving increment of `count` outside the conditional:

```
    while (fgets(singleLine, sizeof singleLine, file) != NULL)
    {
        if (count == lineNumber - 1)
        {
            char *line;

            if ( (line=strchr(singleLine, '\n')) != NULL)
            {
                *line = '\0';
                strncpy(dst, singleLine, dstlen);
            }
            //strcpy(dst, singleLine); // NOT SAFE!!! should use strncpy
            strncpy(dst, singleLine, dstlen);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

I'm sorry, English is not solid ground to me. Hope it helps!